# Pandas sort values alphabetically second character

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, alphabetical

I currently have a dataframe column that looks like below:

```
Location
CJ111
CJ111
CD111
CD111
BQ111
BQ111
BL111
BL111
```

I'm using

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['Location'], ascending=False)
```

I want the df to sort by the second character also eg.

```
Location
CD111
CD111
CJ111
CJ111
BL111
BL111
BQ111
BQ111
```

Is there anyway to achieve this without using a custom sort key?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.str[1]` to get the second character from the Series, then use `argsort` to get [Positions of values within the sort order](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html), which can be further used to order the original data frame:

```
df.loc[df.Location.str[1].argsort()]

#   Location
#2    CD111
#3    CD111
#0    CJ111
#1    CJ111
#6    BL111
#7    BL111
#4    BQ111
#5    BQ111
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use sort_values with an index you can use for an additional sort later on, etc:

Full Code

```
import pandas as pd
lst = ['CJ111','CJ111','CD111','CD111','BQ111','BQ111','BL111','BL111']
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns =['Location']) 
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
idx = df['Location'].str[1:2].sort_values().index
df = df.reindex(idx).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```